# Equicontinuous sequence of functions being uniformly bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Here's the question: Suppose that $(f_n)$ is an equicontinuous sequence in $C^0$ and $p \in [a, b]$ is given. If $f_n(p)$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers, prove that $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded.

How is this true? Why is it that if you choose an arbitrary point $p \in [a, b]$, and obtain a bounded sequence of real numbers $f_n(p)$ (i.e. the values of all of the functions evaluated at this point), then $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded? Can't the value of the functions $\rightarrow - \infty$ somewhere to the left of $p$ or $\rightarrow \infty$ somewhere to the right of $p$?

Thanks.

Comment: This is basically the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem.